# procodile syntax errors trying to start staytus

Tags: gem

Running Ubuntu on AWS to do a proof of concept for staytus. I am super green and have waded through most of my issues to get to this point.

[staytus tutorial](https://atech.blog/atech/install-staytus-tutorial) is what I've been following, and perhaps it's my lack of skills, but I've found it to be left wanting.

[stuff I've had to do beyond the tutorials recommendations to continue through the installation](https://hastebin.com/yedinuyehi.sql) :

```
CREATE DATABASE `staytus` CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
CREATE USER `staytus`@`127.0.0.1` IDENTIFIED BY '*********';
GRANT ALL ON `staytus`.* TO `staytus`@`127.0.0.1`;

staytus:

Ruby 1.99 was installed did this and got ruby 2.4

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ruby2.4
sudo apt-get install ruby2.4-dev

need to update gemfile to show ruby '2.4.4' and then gem install bundler
```

[last error I got](https://hastebin.com/nopakorasa.rb):

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-26-129:/opt/staytus/staytus$ sudo -u staytus procodile start --dev
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/procodile-1.0.19/lib/procodile/cli.rb:160: warning: else without rescue is useless
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/procodile-1.0.19/lib/procodile/cli.rb:57: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
...ort_by { |k,v| k.to_s }.each do |method, options|
...                               ^
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/procodile-1.0.19/lib/procodile/cli.rb:57: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '='
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/procodile-1.0.19/lib/procodile/cli.rb:144: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
          instances.each do |instance|
                           ^
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/procodile-1.0.19/lib/procodile/cli.rb:145: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
            puts "Started".color(32) + " #{inst...
                  ^
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/procodile-1.0.19/lib/procodile/cli.rb:155: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
...upervisor(@config, @options) do |supervisor|
...                               ^
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/procodile-1.0.19/lib/procodile/cli.rb:162: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/procodile-1.0.19/bin/procodile:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/procodile:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/procodile:23:in `<main>'
```

I've seen this block of error prior when trying to do installations, but they aren't exactly google able. Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use this command which should fix your issue

```
gem install procodile
```

I had the same issue. The above fixed the issue

Comment: Can you elaborate, why this has fixed your issue?